# create a csv file and download it

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

First, hi everyone, i'm new and italian so sorry if miss something. i have some issue with these VB.NET code. I need to create a CSV file and instantly download it. But when it comes to the "Me.Context.Response" it doesn't download the file... 
i'm trying to put in this csv file some data from the database which i pass as Parameters. After creating the stringBuilder i want to download it but...

```
Private Sub GenerateCSVFile(tbl As List(Of DBList))

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    Dim separatore As Char = ";"c

    'Debug.Print("RecordCount: " & tbl.Count.ToString())

    '*** Intestazioni di colonna ***
    sb.Append("Articolo/Struttura" & separatore)
    sb.Append("Diametro" & separatore)
    sb.Append("Quantità" & separatore)
    sb.Append("Macchina" & separatore)
    sb.Append("Reparto" & separatore)
    For Each elemento In tbl

        sb.Append(elemento.Articolo + separatore)
        sb.Append(elemento.diametro.ToString + separatore)
        sb.Append(elemento.QtaOrdinata.ToString + separatore)
        Try
            sb.Append(elemento.Macchina.ToString + separatore)
        Catch ex As Exception
            sb.Append("" + separatore)
        End Try
        sb.Append(elemento.Reparto.ToString + separatore)
        'A Capo
        sb.Append(vbCr & vbLf)
    Next

    Dim renderedBytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString())
    Dim fileName As String = "Riepilogo.csv"

    Me.Context.Response.Clear()
    Me.Context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
    Me.Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName))
    Me.Context.Response.BinaryWrite(renderedBytes)
    Me.Context.Response.End()

    'Response.Redirect("~\backOffice\Anagrafica\imgSchemiCarico\Riepilogo.xlsx")
    ' ''Response.Write("<script>window.open('~\backOffice\Anagrafica\imgSchemiCarico\Riepilogo.xlsx','_blank');</script>")


End Sub
```

Comment: ...but what? You didn't explain your problem other than vaguely saying it doesn't download. Do you get any errors? Have you stepped through the code to make sure it does what you expect? I think you probably want Response.Write instead of BinaryWrite - a CSV file is not a binary file, it's a simple text file. Also "text/csv" is the correct MIME type for this kind of file, you can look it up online.

Comment: And why not use a dedicated library to create a CSV, like https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/